# Can't make complex query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with logs from physical access control system looks like:

Table: `logs`

| id | date | obj_id | direction | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 07:56:12 | 1725 | IN | John |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 07:59:43 | 1566 | IN | Peter |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 12:01:35 | 1725 | OUT | John |
| 4 | 2021-01-01 12:43:26 | 1725 | IN | John |
| 5 | 2021-01-01 17:03:18 | 1566 | OUT | Peter |
| 6 | 2021-01-01 17:36:15 | 1725 | OUT | John |
| 7 | 2021-01-02 07:43:28 | 1566 | IN | Peter |
| 8 | 2021-01-02 07:55:16 | 1725 | IN | John |
| 9 | 2021-01-02 17:01:20 | 1566 | OUT | Peter |
| 10 | 2021-01-02 17:13:07 | 1725 | OUT | John |

`date` — event date;
`obj_id` — person's ID;
`direction` — entrance (`IN`) or exit (`OUT`);
`name` — person's name.

I need somehow get query with result looks like:

| day | obj_id | min_in | max_out | minutes | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1725 | 2021-01-01 07:56:12 | 2021-01-01 17:36:15 | 580 | John |
| 2021-01-01 | 1566 | 2021-01-01 07:59:43 | 2021-01-01 17:03:18 | 543 | Peter |
| 2021-01-02 | 1725 | 2021-01-02 07:55:16 | 2021-01-02 17:13:07 | 557 | John |
| 2021-01-02 | 1566 | 2021-01-02 07:43:28 | 2021-01-02 17:01:20 | 557 | Peter |

`day` — day of aggregated data of person's events;
`minutes_in` — something like `ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(max_in, max_out)) / 60)`.

I need to get data (first entry (`min_in`), last exit (`max_out`), time between entry and exit (`minutes`)) from the log table for each day an employee passes through the turnstile in order to generate a report.

Do I need to use subqueries, views, or something else?

Comment: Trivial. Common GROUP BY + some aggregate and scalar functions.

Comment: You need to use `GROUP BY`, `MIN(date)`, `MAX(date)`, and `TIMDIFF(MAX(date), MIN(date))`

Comment: ... and `DATE(datetime)`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through group by:
**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table logs (id int,  date timestamp, obj_id int, direction varchar(10),  name  varchar(10));
insert into logs values(1   ,'2021-01-01 07:56:12'  ,1725   ,'IN',  'John');
insert into logs values(2   ,'2021-01-01 07:59:43', 1566    ,'IN',  'Peter');
insert into logs values(3   ,'2021-01-01 12:01:35'  ,1725   ,'OUT', 'John');
insert into logs values(4   ,'2021-01-01 12:43:26'  ,1725   ,'IN',  'John');
insert into logs values(5   ,'2021-01-01 17:03:18'  ,1566   ,'OUT', 'Peter');
insert into logs values(6   ,'2021-01-01 17:36:15'  ,1725   ,'OUT', 'John');
insert into logs values(7   ,'2021-01-02 07:43:28'  ,1566   ,'IN',  'Peter');
insert into logs values(8   ,'2021-01-02 07:55:16'  ,1725   ,'IN',  'John');
insert into logs values(9   ,'2021-01-02 17:01:20'  ,1566   ,'OUT', 'Peter');
insert into logs values(10  ,'2021-01-02 17:13:07'  ,1725   ,'OUT', 'John');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select day
     , obj_id
     , min_in
     , max_out
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,min_in,max_out) minutes
     , name 
  from 
     ( select date(date) day
            , obj_id 
            , min(case when direction = 'IN' then date end) min_in
            , max(case when direction = 'OUT' then date end) max_out
            , name
         from logs 
        group 
           by date(date)
            , obj_id
            , name
     ) t 
 order 
    by day
     , name;
```

| day | obj_id | min_in | max_out | name | minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1725 | 2021-01-01 07:56:12 | 2021-01-01 17:36:15 | John | 580 |
| 2021-01-01 | 1566 | 2021-01-01 07:59:43 | 2021-01-01 17:03:18 | Peter | 543 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1725 | 2021-01-02 07:55:16 | 2021-01-02 17:13:07 | John | 557 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1566 | 2021-01-02 07:43:28 | 2021-01-02 17:01:20 | Peter | 557 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Not in the original question, but you may need to deal with orphans - "in" and "out" events that aren't matched by "out" and "in" events. Also, people entering one day and exiting the next.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I've changed query a little bit for that cases: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2fwnCmjdyRwuzTghepbxRb/0 :)

Comment: @5kr1p7 that's great. is there any other condition to address?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur now I'm stuck at solving case then person is `OUT` and after `IN` in same day. (`id` 12-14 at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2fwnCmjdyRwuzTghepbxRb/1).

Comment: What's your desired result in this situayion?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Something like https://rentry.co/5mprg